Spring boot Java - Groovy unit tests failing during build time with this error -> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Runtime
We have an API based on Spring boot Java whose unit tests are written in groovy.
main files are in -> src/main/java
unit test files are in -> src/test/groovy
The build tool being used is gradle. Whenever we run build task on intelliJ IDE the, the build task fails due to the class not found exception. My guess is that it's unable to find Runtime class needed to run groovy based unit tests. Here's the error stacktrace.
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 99' finished with non-zero exit value 1
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 99' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:415)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:145)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.access$000(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:42)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess$1.executionFinished(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy92.executionFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:221)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.finished(DefaultExecHandle.java:355)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.completed(ExecHandleRunner.java:110)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Error: Could not find or load main class Runtime
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Runtime
Error: Could not find or load main class Runtime


Tried adding sourceSets and other groovy dependencies.
What am I missing here?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run
your code to answer your question.
